# Error al llegar al imagen en un array

Tags: php, api, woocommerce

Estoy trabajando con la API de WooCommerce no puedo obtener la imagen del producto

producto.php

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 11
    [name] => Remera
    ......
)
[images] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 12
                [date_created] => 2021-09-25T14:19:15
                [date_created_gmt] => 2021-09-25T20:19:15
                [date_modified] => 2021-09-25T14:19:15
                [date_modified_gmt] => 2021-09-25T20:19:15
                [src] => https://tiendawordpress/prueba/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/remera_azul_lisa_3.jpg
                [name] => remera_azul_lisa_3
                [alt] => 
            )

    )
```

Recorro el array

```
$product = $woocommerce->get('products/11');
//echo '<img src="'.$product->src.'">';
```

Y este es el error que tengo

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$src in ... producto.php on line 35

ACTUALIZADO

```
echo $product->images['src'];
```

Hice un cambio para llegar a obtener la imagen pero el error ahora es que no esta definido `src`

> Notice: Undefined index: src in

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: En el products/11, no cerraste la comilla.

Comment: Listo... gracias

Comment: Si haces un var_dump() de $product, obtienes todos los datos igual ?

Comment: Si: ` "src" => string 77 http s:/ / tiendawordpress/prueba/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/remera_azul_lisa_3.jpg`

Comment: Tienes la imagen dentro de un array, deberías acceder a el de esta forma `$product->images[0]['src']`

Comment: @RimuruTempest, tambien lo hice y este es el error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como recorres el array? Ahí esta la respuesta.

```
foreach ($product->images as $row) {
    echo '<img src="'.$row->src.'">';
}
```

Tenes que recorrer el array de `images` para llegar a la imagen que está en `src`. Lo mismo con el resto.

Besitos

Comment: Claro, es verdad, no me había dado cuenta... ahí me trajo la imagen. Gracias Antonia.